# Store data from Zigbee Embedded device

Tags: database, web-applications, embedded, protocols, sensors

Hello I am working on wireless sensor network (Zigbee). WSN gateway device have a ethernet. the gateway device actually manage the network and get the reading from sensors like temperature,light,humidity,pressure sensor etc. My question is how can I store/send data to a remote database or protocol/Application. I mean, Is there any protocol/Application which suitable for it? I want to dispatch those data over web and any application/protocol get the packet and store it to database with correct sequence.Is there any way to do it?? I am using vaadin web application framework for front end. Which fetch the sensor data and show it to user along with graph,chart etc. If additional information require I will glad to provide.

Thank You

Shantanu Banerjee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are writing directly "to the wire" and are looking for a protocol to handle that data.  If that understanding is incorrect, then you can quit reading now because I didn't understand the question.

If the assumption is correct, however, then one possibility might be to use [OData](http://www.odata.org/).  At each read of the data, make an HTTP POST request to the server. The viability of this depends somewhat on the volume of data and the bandwidth. The HTTP requests for OData are a bit heavy, but if you used JSON (as opposed to XML), it would reduce the overall size some.

You would need a database engine that has an OData service available (and there are a few).  I don't know what the data looks like, but presumably you could define a table to store each record with a field for each reading value.  Suppose the table is named `readings`, then a POST to the service with two values might look like this:

```
POST http://servername.domain/fullURL/v1/readings HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{
 "temperature": 1.2,
 "otherdata": 42
}
```

Comment: I want a portable tiny library which can handle http soap request or response. I mean I want to parse those xml data and handle events as require.